# Bijection between the set of all Partitions and the set of all Algebras

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-partition

I am interested in showing that, given a set $S$ there exists a bijection between the set of all [algebras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebra_of_sets) of $S$, denoted $A$ and the set of all [partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20a%20partition%20of,stamp%20is%20in%20a%20bundle.) of $S$, denoted $P$.

As a simple example, I considered the set $S=\{1, 2, 3\}.$ Then, the set of all partitions $P$ consists exactly of the  the sets
$$ \{\{1 \}, \{2\}, \{3 \}\}, \{\{1, 2\}, \{3\}\}, \{\{1\}, \{2, 3\}\}, \{\{2\}, \{1, 3\}\}, \{1, 2, 3\}.$$ I then computed the set of all algebra and found that it consisted of all the following sets: $$\{\emptyset, S\}, \{\{1\}, \{2,3\}, S, \emptyset\},\{\{2\}, \{1,3\}, S, \emptyset\}, \{\{3\}, \{1,2\}, S, \emptyset\}, 2^S.$$

It does seem like both sets have the same number of elements, but I am not sure how to construct the bijection in this case. One possible map that came to mind was the map $f:P\to A$,
$$f:P\mapsto \{S, \emptyset\} \cup P$$
for all partitions except the one consisting of all the singleton, and for the later,
$$f:\{\{x_0\}: x\in S\} \mapsto 2^S. $$
The map seems to be bijective in this case, but does it work for the general case?
If not, what is the correct mapping?

Answer (score 4):

As long as $S$ is **finite**, such a bijection does indeed exist and have a nice description. You're being slightly mislead by the case $S=\{1,2,3\}$ when you suggest your $f$, though; think e.g. about $S=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ and the partition $P=\{\{1,2\},\{3,4\},\{5,6\}\}$.

Instead, you want the algebra *generated by* the elements of the partition $P$. This is just the smallest algebra containing $P$ as a subset; in particular, for the above $P$ it would be $$\{\emptyset, \{1,2\},\{3,4\},\{5,6\},\{1,2,3,4\},\{1,2,5,6\},\{3,4,5,6\},\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}\}.$$

Every partition gives rise to an algebra in this way. To go the other way, given an algebra $\mathcal{A}$ of subsets of a set $S$ we want to look at the partition of $S$ into minimal nonempty elements of $\mathcal{A}$ (called "atoms"). **As long as $S$ is finite** this always gives rise to a partition $P$ such that the algebra generated by $P$ is precisely $\mathcal{A}$; however, this can fail for infinite $S$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Why is it the case that the partition of $\mathcal{A}$ into minimal non-empty elements generates the algebra $\mathcal{A}$?

Comment: Consider a minimal nonempty set $X$ which is not generated by atoms (This exists because of finiteness).  It’s not an atom, so it contains some atom $A$. $X/A$ is then a smaller nonempty set not generated by atoms causing a contradiction.

Comment: @Dispersion For $x\in S$, let $x_\mathcal{A}$ be the smallest set in $\mathcal{A}$ containing $x$; the existence of this follows from the finiteness of $S$ (exercise). Now any $X\in\mathcal{A}$ can be written as $$X=\bigcup_{x\in X}x_\mathcal{A}.$$

Comment: @NoahSchweber I see, by the smallest set in $\mathcal{A}$ containing $x$, do you also mean the minimal element of $\mathcal{A}$ containing $x$? I was also wondering what a counter example would be for infinite $S$.

Comment: Additionally, I was wondering why the partition of $S$ taken from minimal elements is unique?